# Uploading from CSV with first and last name in the came column

Tags: contacts

I am uploading lots of CSV files and using addressee and addressee custom it will skip the first and last name and leave me to do it manually.

edit: while renaming i realized I derped and addressee is something else.

Is there anyway to get first and last names separated from one column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using excel / libre office / google sheets, you might want to use the built in spread sheet functionality to split the name column into two columns

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20split%20a%20name%20column%20in%20excel

Might be a lot easier and faster to do so locally.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to re-generate first and last name from the addressee column? I assume you want to do this with an SQL query or with a script? If so, yes you can (but you have to be carefull as you are editing directly in the DB and such....). The table is civicrm_contact and the columns are: first_name, last_name and addressee_display.
Otherwise I would recommend removing the contacts and starting over I am afraid...

Comment: It was more in the upload contacts, i have their first and last name in one column and i have bee putting it in addressee.

Is there a way to directly put the first and last name in from the same column when uploading from a CSV file.

Comment: I see :-) No, I do not think you can do that in the standard import. You would probably have to integrate the 2 fields into 1 in your csv before you import.